# Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js): SassError: Can't find stylesheet to import: @use '@angular/material' as mat;

Tags: angular, angular-material

hey guys i have no clue why i cant use this stylesheet. i have read other threads about this issue but none of the solutions worked for me. i am a newb to angular and pulling my hair out. keep getting Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js): SassError: Can't find stylesheet to import: @use '@angular/material' as mat; no matter what i do. here is my .scss and angular.json files:

```scss
// Custom Theming for Angular Material
// For more information: https://material.angular.io/guide/theming
@use '@angular/material' as mat;
// Plus imports for other components in your app.

// Include the common styles for Angular Material. We include this here so that you only
// have to load a single css file for Angular Material in your app.
// Be sure that you only ever include this mixin once!
@include mat.core();

// Define the palettes for your theme using the Material Design palettes available in palette.scss
// (imported above). For each palette, you can optionally specify a default, lighter, and darker
// hue. Available color palettes: https://material.io/design/color/
$theme-primary: mat.define-palette(mat.$indigo-palette);
$theme-accent: mat.define-palette(mat.$pink-palette, A200, A100, A400);

// The warn palette is optional (defaults to red).
$theme-warn: mat.define-palette(mat.$red-palette);

// Create the theme object. A theme consists of configurations for individual
// theming systems such as "color" or "typography".
$theme: mat.define-light-theme((
  color: (
    primary: $theme-primary,
    accent: $theme-accent,
    warn: $theme-warn,
  ),
  typography: mat.define-typography-config(),
));

// Include theme styles for core and each component used in your app.
// Alternatively, you can import and @include the theme mixins for each component
// that you are using.
@include mat.all-component-themes($theme);
```

```json
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "movieSearch": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss"
        },
        "@schematics/angular:application": {
          "strict": true
        }

      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "progress": false,
            "outputPath": "dist",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
            "aot": true,
            "assets": [
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "src/styles.scss"
             
            ],
            "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
              "includePaths": [ "node_modules/" ]
            },
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "500kb",
                  "maximumError": "1mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "2kb",
                  "maximumError": "4kb"
                }
              ],
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ]
             
            },
            "development": {
              "buildOptimizer": false,
              "optimization": false,
              "vendorChunk": true,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true,
              "namedChunks": true
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "movieSearch:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "browserTarget": "movieSearch:build:development",
              "proxyConfig": "proxy.conf.js"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "movieSearch:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "assets": [
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        },
        "server": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:server",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist-server",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.server.json"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "dev": {
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": true
            },
            "production": {
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "movieSearch",
  "cli": {
    "analytics": false
  }
}
```

package.json:

```json
{
  "name": "moviesearch",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "prestart": "node aspnetcore-https",
    "start": "run-script-os",
    "start:windows": "ng serve --port 44400 --ssl --ssl-cert %APPDATA%\\ASP.NET\\https\\%npm_package_name%.pem --ssl-key %APPDATA%\\ASP.NET\\https\\%npm_package_name%.key",
    "start:default": "ng serve --port 44400 --ssl --ssl-cert $HOME/.aspnet/https/${npm_package_name}.pem --ssl-key $HOME/.aspnet/https/${npm_package_name}.key",
    "build": "ng build",
    "build:ssr": "ng run movieSearch:server:dev",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    
    
    
   
 
    "@angular/platform-server": "^15.0.4",
   
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
    "jquery": "^3.6.0",
    "oidc-client": "^1.11.5",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.0",
    "run-script-os": "^1.1.6",
    "@angular/animations": "~15.0.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "15.0.3",
    "@angular/common": "~15.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~15.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "~15.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~15.0.0",
    "@angular/material": "15.0.3",
    "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "15.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~15.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~15.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "~15.0.0",
    "moment": "^2.18.1",
    "rxjs": "~7.4.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^15.0.4",
    "@angular/cli": "^15.0.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^15.0.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~4.0.3",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.10",
    "@types/node": "^18.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.2.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.1",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^2.0.0",
    "typescript": "~4.8.4"
  },
  "overrides": {
    "autoprefixer": "10.4.5"
  }
}
```

have tried ng updates all day, using different options in angular.json etc. feel like I'm missing the tiniest thing but its hard to find.

Comment: The content of package.json could be also usefull. Can you add it?